# Are our moderators still interested in being moderators? If not, are there others interested?

Tags: discussion

Over time, I've seen less and less active participation from our current moderation group (Which is understandable). I don't want to take anything away from the job they did helping the site define itself and grow to the point it's at now. However, even though we are a lower traffic SE site, we still do generate flags and have the occasional spammer to deal with.

Currently the last visit on the regular site are:

- Greg - 1.28.16
- Ivo Flipse - 1.14.16
- Matt Chan - 2.7.16 (Matt is the most regular of the mods, he checks at least once a week)
- Nathan Wheeler - 1.28.15 (Not a typo)

Last visits on Meta

- Greg - 11.9.15
- Ivo - 1.14.16
- Matt - 1.12.16
- Nathan - 2.11.14

I'd like to find out if the current moderators are still interested in being moderators, and if not, if there are any other site regulars that might be interested in being considered for the position.

Comment: Now that I'm reading this again, that 2/5 of the mods haven't been on meta in several months is pretty bad.

Comment: @Meta - Thank you. They are still transitioning and doing other tasks, I expect an announcement for all the new moderators to be coming along from the CM team in due time.

Answer (score 8):

While it's a little unusual for this matter to be discussed so wide out in the open, it's by no means a bad thing. It's perfectly expected that moderators may need a break, or have a change in priorities. So, thanks for getting this conversation started JohnP.

For reference, we do indeed require that Stack Exchange sites have a minimum of three moderators, regardless of how quiet the site might be. We consider that the minimum number of caretakers needed for the community to properly govern itself.

But I digress. Sounds like this is a good time to give a couple of the current mods a well-earned break. The community team will be in touch with the moderation team to work out next steps.

Answer (score 7):

I would actually be willing to let another member of this site take over my moderator position. This site has been around for many years now. It's had its ups and downs, Stack Exchange has changed and grown too, and my life has reached a point where I cannot devote as much time as I originally used to for this site.

Typically mods who haven't checked in for a while should be removed although I don't know what the official process is. This would be a matter that the Community Team should be engaged in, and I think it would be best to contact them and possibly get have new moderator(s) nominated or step up for the role.

Comment: I was planning on that if it was needed. I'll wait a bit to see if the other moderators see/weigh in or not. If it is needed, do you want to contact the CM team or would you rather I do it?

Comment: John, for whatever it's worth I think I emailed the community team (or used a form, or something) maybe ~9 months ago and asked about the moderator positions and they basically said "thanks, we're full, have a nice day."

Comment: I'll reach out to them and see what they say.

Comment: @MattChan - Have you heard anything back from the CM team?

Comment: @JohnP Hey John, sorry for the delay. This has been an unfortunate busy week for me. I'm contacting them now. I'll update (or let them) once I hear back.

Comment: @MattChan - No worries, I was curious.

Comment: @MattChan I think it's worth bringing up that things like the blog feature would probably get some traction with new folks. Some of us have reliably been coming here nearly every day for years at this point. Personally, I really enjoy knowing that even as a high score regular, everything I do is still subject to peer review and open comment. Call me corny, but I dig fitness.stackexchange.com

Comment: I still haven't heard anything from the Community Team. I'll ping again.

Answer (score 3):

Ditto with Matt's answer. I try to stop by now and again, but I have much less bandwidth than I used to. This site could certainly use some more help, and I wouldn't be offended at all to be replaced to free up the "seat".

Comment: I tried to email the community team; no idea if it will go through.

Comment: @Greg, have you tried reaching out to the Community Team? My e-mails have still gone unanswered.

Comment: @MattChan - I got a response from a CM yesterday, she's taking a look today (3.1.16)

Comment: @JohnP , get any love back from them?

Comment: @EricKaufman - Not yet, but the CM team is pretty busy. I'll keep pinging occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

As a newer user, I feel like moving onwards to the level of moderator through the standard points system would take me a inordinate amount of time based on the number of questions being asked in the day. I am also concerned that the current moderating team are not checking the page daily as spam has been sat on the front page for over 15 hours.

Can someone explain to me how the community team works with relation to the moderator team?

edit: I did not understand the difference in beta score requirements for moderation vs established exchange scores.

Comment: See my answer. Points dont matter for appointment/election as a qualifier, but tgey are a consideration.

Comment: @Jjosaur if you're not going to be around to be a part of the community as a non-moderator, you're probably not who anyone's looking for as a moderator. The "inordinate amount of time" issue is what actually makes you a decent mod. You need to have been around this place long enough get a sense for the content, questions, and on/off-topic. It's about good judgement and long term consistency and engagement, in my opinion.

Comment: I stand corrected, I was not aware of the difference between the score required for actions on a beta exchange vs a established exchange. I was thinking you needed over 2000 to start doing any moderation which would take a much larger amount of time on a beta over an established exchange.

Comment: Ah, there are some moderation tools available to high rep users. You have been providing solid answers, rep will accumulate faster than you think.

Answer (score 1):

The community team selects appropriate people for beta sites. They are working on it, but it just takes time. Best thing to xo is flag he question/answer as spam. Enough votes and the system hides it.

For graduated sites there are regular elections.